# If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and it is en eigenvector of $B$, why must it be the case that it is an eigenvetor of $A^{-1}B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For $A$ and $B$ of the same size, and $Av$ = $\lambda_1v$ and $Bv = \lambda_2v$ why must it be true that $v$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}B$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider applying $A^{-1}B$ to the vector $v$.  (By the way, you assumed that $A$ was invertible).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "applying"?

Comment: Plug $v$ it into $A^{-1}B$.  In other words, calculate $(A^{-1}B)v$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $\exists A^{-1}$. Notice that since $A$ is invertible and $v \neq 0$, then $Av\neq 0$, therefore $\lambda_1\neq 0$.  Since $Av=\lambda_1 v$, by applying $A^{-1}$ to both sides, it follows that $v=\lambda_1A^{-1}v$, therefore $A^{-1}v=\frac{v}{\lambda_1}$. Finally:

$$A^{-1}Bv=A^{-1}(\lambda_2v)=\lambda_2A^{-1}(v)=\frac{\lambda_2}{\lambda_1}v.$$